# Is it "a" or "an" in front of Greek letters beginning with a vowel?

Tags: article-writing, translation-request

Good evening!

I know that it is a basic rule in English that before most vowels, the indefinite particle *a* becomes *an*.
My question now is: Does this also apply in front of (non-latenized) Greek letters?

For example, is it "*a* $\omega$-invariant" or "*an* $\omega$-invariant"?

Comment: There are language stack exchanges, by the way.

Comment: It's the sound, not the letter. Thus, you carry an umbrella but you wear a uniform.

Comment: Thank you! I was like 99% sure this was the case, but better safe than sorry ^^

Comment: You can check these by using Google, add quotes around and search for it, like [a ω-invariant](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22a%20%CF%89%2Dinvariant%22). You get lots of things like $A(\omega)$, and you find many more results for the "an" version.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Part of your comment reversed *a* and *an*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule is whether the pronunciation of the letter name starts with a vowel.  So:

- Use *an* before $\alpha$, $\epsilon$, $\eta$*, $\iota$**, $\omicron$, $\upsilon$, and $\omega$.
- Use $a$ before all other Greek letters.

(* Unless you pronounce it "heta".)

(** Unless you pronounce it "yota".)